# OpenBSD - How does one set an alias?

Tags: ksh, alias, openbsd, csh

I am running the latest OpenBSD and I cannot figure out how to set a simple alias, something along the lines of cls=clear.
I've tried putting it in ~/.cshrc and in ~/.profile.
I've tried:

```
alias cls clear
alias cls=clear
alias cls='clear'
alias cls="clear"
```

Nothing works.

On another but perhaps related note:
If echo $SHELL tells me I'm using /bin/ksh, why a ~/.cshrc instead of ~/.kshrc?

Comment: What part of the OpenBSD doco told you to use a `.cshrc`?

Comment: No one told me to use a .cshrc. But when I do a simple install of OpenBSD that's what is created in ~/.

Comment: Putting the alias in ~/.profile should have worked; you would have to log out & log in again -- or source the file in the existing shells.  Do you still encounter a failure after doing that?

Comment: OK. That works when I first boot up, but if I try it after starting X (startx is how I do it) I get: /bin/ksh:cls: not found

Answer (score 5):

`.cshrc` is copied over from `/etc/skel` because it exists there and that's what happens to the contents of `/etc/skel` on (most) user account additions. However that's totally unrelated to `sh` or `ksh`; `.cshrc` exists due to `csh` being installed and supported since the 2BSD days (a tradition, at this point).

`.profile` is only read by login shells, so commands there will not be picked up by new shells that are not login shells:

```
valen$ cd
valen$ ed .profile
215
a
echo .profile was run
.
wq
237
valen$ exec ksh
valen$ exec ksh -l
.profile was run
valen$
```

The [`ksh(1)` manual](http://man.openbsd.org/man1/ksh.1) has docs on setting an `ENV` environment variable that non-login instances of `ksh` will read:

```
valen$ ed .profile
237
d
a
export ENV=$HOME/.profile
echo now with ENV set
.
wq
263
valen$ exec ksh
valen$ exec ksh -l
now with ENV set
now with ENV set
valen$ exec ksh
now with ENV set
valen$
```

Given the double-read of `~/.profile` with `export ENV=$HOME/.profile` set, it may instead be better to have a different file, such as `~/.kshrc` as recommended by the manual that contains your custom aliases:

```
valen$ cat .profile
PATH=$HOME/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/games
export PATH HOME TERM
export ENV=$HOME/.kshrc
valen$ cat .kshrc
alias cls=clear
valen$ exec ksh -l
valen$ alias | grep cls
cls=clear
valen$
```

Comment: That works. Thanks to both of you for taking the time to help. I appreciate it.

Comment: When using X it is better to set ENV to something other than `.profile`. A good convention is `$HOME/.kshrc`. Reusing .profile may result in a PATH with duplicate entries in this case.